# Can i get the key of a style in code-behind? (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, styles

If I have the following code:

```
Style defaultStyle = (Style)FindResource("MyTestStyle");
```

Is there a way to get the name of the style (i.e. reverse-lookup)? Something like:

```
string name = defaultStyle.SomeMagicLookUpFunction()
```

Where name would evaluate to "MyTestStyle."

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've created a small helper class with a single method to do the reverse lookup that you require.

```
public static class ResourceHelper
{
    static public string FindNameFromResource(ResourceDictionary dictionary, object resourceItem)
    {
        foreach (object key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            if (dictionary[key] == resourceItem)
            {
                return key.ToString();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

you can call it using the following

```
string name = ResourceHelper.FindNameFromResource(this.Resources, defaultStyle);
```

Every `FrameworkElement` has it's own `.Resources` dictionary, using 'this' assumes you're in the right place for where MyTestStyle is defined. If needs be you could add more methods to the static class to recursively traverse all the dictionaries in a window (application ?)

Comment: Or just have it start from some FrameworkElement and work breadth-first through the visual tree.

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the example above slightly to get it work for me, since I use MergedDictionaries.  If the above example gives you 0 results, try this:

```
  //Called by FindNameFromResource(aControl.Style) 
    static public string FindNameFromResource(object resourceItem) 
    {

        foreach (ResourceDictionary dictionary in App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
        {
            foreach (object key in dictionary.Keys)
            {
                if (dictionary[key] == resourceItem)
                {
                    return key.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without searching resource dictionaries, I don't think this is possible as x:Key is part of the XAML markup grammar and has no relevance when you have a reference to a Style or DataTemplate or anything you've retrieved.

Have a look at the MSDN document on [x:Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not using the Style object, but if you go stumping around in the [ResourceDictionary containing your style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources.aspx) you can get the x:Key.

Answer (score 0):

The IF statement needs to compare strings as below

```
    public static class ResourceHelper
    {
        static public string FindNameFromResource(ResourceDictionary dictionary, object resourceItem)
        {
            foreach (object key in dictionary.Keys)
            {
                if (key.Equals(resourceItem))
                {
                    return key.ToString();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```