# Get button style name

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I have several styles on Window.Resources that I apply to several buttons with C#. Then I need to change the style but first I need to know what is the current style that is applied to the button I want to change the style.
I can't find the way to get the style name from the button!

Comment: Try that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538750/can-i-get-the-key-of-a-style-in-code-behind-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Button.Style` property? If explcit setting of style is done using resource `Key` then you should get the current style of the button using `Button.Style` propetry otherwise it is a little tricky to gather all `Style` related information at a control level.

And there are reasons for this. Styles are inherited and could be overriden at distinct element scopes such as App, Window, UserControl, Ancestor UIElements and finally the individual control. So when you access `Button.Style` property you get a style that was the last immediate style applied to the `Button`. If the style is `BasedOn` another `Style` then `Style.BasedOn` will give you the parent / base `Style`. Again if that `BasedOn` style is derived from another `Style` we will get that as `Style.basedOn.BasedOn`... etc.

I hope this makes sense. :-)

Comment: button.style returns a style, not the name of the style!

Comment: Why would a Style carry a name? It should carry a Key if possible. In case iof you want to know the name then try `Style.Name` property. But Styles or other resources generally carry a `Key`. This `Key` can be a string name or it can be a Type object e.g. BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" is one such style wheer key is a the Type `TextBox` i.e. a global style applied to all textBoxes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a mistake in terms of design/architecture if you approach your issue this way. If you need to change styles conditionally you can create UI-elements based on objects which hold the relevant information using [data-binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question (+1).

This is just my thought which may not be very accurate. I doubt if it makes sense to get a style for a UI control. Suppose you apply style "style1" to an UI control and then you can set individual attributes like foreground/background.... Now, what would be the style?

If you want to maintain/track the state of the button, that should be handled either as visual states or in your code behind (ViewModel/Model) probably.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.style.aspx)

```
public void FooFunc()
{
    Button myButton = ...;

    Console.WriteLine("The Style: {0}", myButton.Style);
}
```

I think that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I'm using this function from another stackoverflow.. it works and returns the style name into a string!

```
static public string FindNameFromResource(ResourceDictionary dictionary, object resourceItem)

static public string FindNameFromResource(ResourceDictionary dictionary, object resourceItem)
        {
            foreach (object key in dictionary.Keys)
            {
                if (dictionary[key] == resourceItem)
                {
                    return key.ToString();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Max,
I'm new to WPF, and had to toggle my Border object's style between one of two known Styles it can have.  Rather than use the linear search in FindNameFromResource, I instead instead did this ...

```
Style normal = (Style)this.Resources["NormalBorder"];
Style strong = (Style)this.Resources["StrongBorder"];
border.Style = border.Style == normal ? strong : normal;
```