# Retrieve x:Name or x:Key from Brush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MyBrush1" x:Key="MyBrush1" Color="Red" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

C#:

```
brush = userControl.FindResource("MyBrush1")
```

How can I retrieve the x:Name or x:Key from **brush**? Is that possible to retrieve them by doing the following:

```
brush.Name
```

or

```
brush.Key
```

Comment: You can scan the ResourceDictionary looking for your object, then that gives you the key. See here for some code:.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538750/can-i-get-the-key-of-a-style-in-code-behind-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class ResourceHelper
{
    public static string FindNameFromResource(ResourceDictionary dictionary, 
           object resourceItem)
    {
        return (dictionary.Contains(resourceItem)) ? 
               dictionary[resourceItem].ToString() : 
               string.Empty;
    }
}
```

helper class with a single method to do the reverse lookup

You can call it like this:

```
string name = ResourceHelper.FindNameFromResource(this.Resources, defaultStyle);
```

Comment: If the resource refers to any **DynamicResource**, then this function does not work. Also, if the resource gets **cloned**, the cloned one cannot be found throw this function neither. Otherwise, the function should work fine.